# ¿Como Sumar dos Input de tipo TIME automáticamente en HTML sin restricción de las 24 horas?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos input de tipo TIME y lo que busco es sumar en otro input automaticamente, 
y que no halla restriccion de las 24 horas, osea que sea asi:

INPUT 1-  15:00:00

INPUT 2-  13:00:00

TOTAL -   28:00:00

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SUMA TIME</title>

</head>
<body>

    Tiempo 1: <input type="time" id="time1"><br>
    Tiempo 2: <input type="time" id="time2"><br> 
    TOTAL: <input type="time" id="total"><br> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: los input time van desde 00:00 hasta 23:59. No puedes poner ahí un 28:00 a menos que lo hagas como texto

Comment: claro,puedo ingresar los valores en un input de tipo TIME  y expresarlos en un input de tipo TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer la suma de los tiempos esto te entregará la cantidad de milisegundos por lo que habrá que formatearlo para obtener el resultado esperado

```js
function SumarTiempos(){
 
    var input1 = document.getElementById('time1');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('time2');
   var strMsg = '';
    
    var date1 = input1.valueAsDate;
    var date2 = input2.valueAsDate;
    
    var s = (date1.getTime() + date2.getTime());
    
    var ms = s % 1000;
   s = (s - ms) / 1000;
   var secs = s % 60;
   s = (s - secs) / 60;
   var mins = s % 60;
   var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;
    
    strMsg = hrs + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
    
 document.getElementById('resultado').value = strMsg;
}
```

```html
Fecha1: <input id="time1" type="time" value="00:00"><br>
Fecha2: <input id="time2" type="time" value="00:00"><br>
<button onclick="SumarTiempos()">Clic me</button><br>
Tiempo Final: <input id="resultado" type="text">
```

NOTA: siempre puedes usar librerías como date.js o moment.js que tienen este tipo de funciones ya listas

Comment: se puede realizar esto pero sin la necesidad del boton

Comment: claro, habría que eliminar el botón y a cada input agregarle `onchange="SumarTiempos()"`